# How to fix cmake error trying to install portmidi?

Tags: 18.04, java, compiling, environment-variables

I am following instructions to install portmidi on ubuntu 18.04

```
README_LINUX.txt for PortMidi
Roger Dannenberg
14 Oct 2009

To make PortMidi, you need cmake and the Java SDK.
Go back up to the portmidi directory and type:

ccmake .

Type 'c' (configure) and then 'g' (generate). You may have
to manually set JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH and JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY
by typing 't' (toggle to advanced mode) and using the 
editor to change the fields. You can find possible values
for JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH by typing "locate jni.h", and for
JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY by typing locate libjvm".

You also need JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2, but this will normally
be set automatically after you set JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH and
run "configure" (type "c" to ccmake). Normally,
JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 is the linux subdirectory within
JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH.
```

but I get an error

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
 Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake
 files:
 JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH (ADVANCED)
```

I have tried installing java with `sudo apt install default-jre` and set my JAVA_HOME variable with `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/java`

but I still get this error

Comment: Which instruction are you trying to follow? What is your full Ubuntu version (18.04 LTS or 18.10)?

Comment: I have updated my post with the information :

Comment: You need to install a JDK I think (not just a JRE) ex. `sudo apt install default-jdk`

Comment: Where can we download the software to reproduce your steps (and maybe problem)?